# How to enlarge the curly brackets in Aligned environment in LyX

Tags: equations, lyx, brackets

I input multiple line equations following the fantastic answer to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300429/how-to-have-a-single-vertically-centred-equation-number-for-multiline-equation-ired-equation-number-for-multiline-equation-i). The only problem is that the curly brackets are too small. I tried the suggestions in the detailed manual of LyX, but failed.

Urgent help is needed as my thesis is due tomorrow! Hope this is the last question before my submission. I really appreciate all your prompt answers which helped me convert my thesis from an ugly word into an elegant Classicthesis style within one week!

Codes:

```
$\begin{aligned}W & =a+b+c\\
& \quad+\frac{e}{d}\{\left[\frac{\frac{e}{d}+\frac{e}{d}}{d}+\frac{\frac{e} {d}+\frac{e}{d}}{d}\right]\\
& \quad\quad\quad-\left[\frac{\frac{e}{d}+\frac{e}{d}}{d}+\frac{\frac{e}{d}+\frac{e}{d}}{d}\right]+\frac{e}{d}\}\\
& =f+g
\end{aligned}
$
```

unwanted output with too small curly brackets:

[image]

Comment: If you want people to help you with your problems, you should consider [accepting the answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/30280) to your other questions if they solved your problems. As of now, you have accepted zero answers. Upvoting and accepting is the TeX.SX-way of saying "thanks".

Comment: The GUI route is described in the first part of [Math symbol question: Vertical bar for 'evaluated at ...'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40166) Just use a brace instead of a bar.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- i don't use lyx, but i think it likely that the braces must be matched on the same line if `\left` and `\right` are used.  a dummy indicated by a period is used in "conventional" latex to match.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are so right.  I wasn't thinking.  I will delete my earlier comment.

Comment: You might try adding `\Biggl` before the `\{` and `\Biggr` before the `\}`.

Comment: I am new to this place and I think I tried my best to click almost all upward arrows to  the helpful answers and comments so far. I don't know that there are new ways to accept answers. I am very happy to appreciate in all ways after submission but how to do this?

Comment: @Wendy Only the questioner can accept an answer to her/his own question. Other users can upvote useful questions or answers. It's also possible to downvote bad answers or questions, but it's done quite sparingly on this site.

Comment: @egreg I only found the "answer your question" red button. Is this what you refer to as accepting an answer if I post my try based on previous comments?

Comment: Both Torbjørn and  Steven's solutions work for my purpose. But Torbjørn's solution has two extra advantages: it adjusts to the variable sizes, and no ERT is required, which is a nice feature for LyX users who are not familier with codes. Thx a lot again for all your quick help!

Comment: @Wendy See the link i provided in the first comment about how to accept answers.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sound's like Wendy would like you to convert your comment into an answer, so she could accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The general way of doing this is described in [Math symbol question: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at ...''](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40160/math-symbol-question-vertical-bar-for-evaluated-at/40166#40166) :

To insert a delimiter of a given, or variable, size, click the *Insert delimiter* button on the math toolbar: [image: button]

In your case you want to select a brace as left delimiter, and *None* as the right delimiter, on the first line. Vice versa on the second line. In this case you will likely get the same size braces on both lines, but if there wasn't a big fraction on the second line as well, you would get a smaller brace there. In that case select a specific size for the brace instead of *Variable*.